# How to create a shortcut for task to run for local services in windows 10?

Tags: asp.net, windows, batch-file, winapi, architecture

I have Bluetooth headphone, sometimes windows 10 fails to connect with Bluetooth device so I need to go to task manager -> Services - Open Services -> Find Bluetooth Support Service and restart it.

I was curious if I can make any shortcut or batch file operation or kind of script and I can just click on it and it will restart Bluetooth Support Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find your service name by typing this command:

```
powershell -Command "sc.exe query | Select-String -Pattern Bluetooth -Context 1,0"
```

You'll find your service's name with the string `SERVICE_NAME` just above the `DISPLAY_NAME` you searched for. It can be something like `UmRdpService` or `RasMan`, whatever.

Then, in an **ELEVATED** command prompt, type these two commands:

```
sc stop YourServiceNameFoundAbove
sc start YourServiceNameFoundAbove
```

Your service is now restarted.

You can use the following batch, it will ask automatically for elevation if needed.
Just modify the line `set SRV=...` and save it where it suits you, then you simply need to create a shortcut manually (done only once) on your desktop.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set SRV=YourServiceNameFoundPreviously

REM Check admin mode, auto-elevate if required.
openfiles > NUL 2>&1 || (
    REM Not elevated. Do it.
    echo createObject^("Shell.Application"^).shellExecute "%~dpnx0", "%*", "", "runas">"%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs"
    cscript /nologo "%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs"
    goto :eof
)
del /s /q "%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs" > NUL 2>&1

sc stop !SRV! || (
    echo ERROR: Couldn't stop service !SRV!.
    pause
    goto :eof
)
sc start !SRV! || (
    echo ERROR: Couldn't start service !SRV!.
    pause
    goto :eof
)
goto :eof
```

Comment: This gives error "[SC] ControlService FAILED 1051: A stop control has been sent to a service that other running services are dependent on." the service name for Bluetooth Support Service is bthserv. I found "Blutooth Handsfree Service" (Service Name: BthHFSrv) depend on this service.

Comment: It means that some other services require this one, so you can't stop it "as it". Type `net stop bthserv`, it will give you the display names of the dependent services.
Stop them first, then stop `bthserv`, then restart `bthserv`, then these services.

Comment: I created batch file as you said, changed little bit as "echo y | net stop !SRV! || ..." and that resolved dependency problem with auto Y. Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. For stopping service, yes, but it won't work with all languages (for French Windows, like mine, you'll need to type `O` for "Oui"). Also, it would probably **NOT** restart the dependent services: that's the major problem and why I gave you the advice to do it manually with `sc` instead. Really, it's better and safer to do the little work once and be quiet forever after that.